# Selecting lines of code in Pycharm is working strangely

Tags: copy, pycharm, copy-paste

Recently, I wrote a block of code, and tried to copy and paste some functions around the code.  But when highlighting the block of code I am trying to select, it exhibits strange behaviour.  The first picture is the faulty case, and the second picture is the normal case.

[image: Faulty highlighting]

[image: Normal highlighting]

First of all, I can click anywhere on my script even though I dont have spaces there.. if that makes sense (sorry I cant explain it any other way).  Second, when I drag my mouse up, it drags up for only that section.  Looking at the faulty screen shot, if I were to copy that block, it would only copy the parts in blue...  Normally when I drag my mouse up, it automatically highlights the whole line as seen in the normal picture.  Also, notice the giant white line on the faulty highlighting compared to the normal highlighting.  I am wondering how I can go back to my old normal highlighting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I was able to reproduce the problem by enabling `column selection mode`.

Try going to `Edit-->Column Selection Mode`. Uncheck it. If this was the problem, perhaps it was a finger flub which performed a shortkey operation.